# how to echo a php array to the jquery $.each method

Tags: jquery

How can I echo a php array to the jquery $.each function?

Here's what I tried so far in php...

```
                  $index = 0;

                  while(!feof($file))
                  {
                     $singleLine = fgets($file);
                     $totalLines[$index] = $singleLine;

                     ++$index;
                  }
                  echo $totalLines;
```

Here's how I'm reading it back in jquery...

```
       $.post("sendFile.php",{fileName: sendFileName}, function(data)
       {
              $.each(data, function(index, value)
              {
                        alert(value);
              });
       });
```

The output is giving me Array...when it should be giving me Test1, Test2, Test3 for each array element...

Comment: try $.ajax and send data by json and also get by the json i think that will work for you

Comment: @mayank-swami - $.post just wraps around $.ajax, so $.post is fine. It just needs a fourth parameter, the format. Eg: $.post('file.php', {field:value}, function(data){..}, 'json'); Then it'll be parsed back as JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to encode your data.

```
echo json_encode($totalLines);
```

And your php code could simply be written as below: (use [file](http://jp.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function to read entire file into an array)

```
echo json_encode(file($file));
// or if need to skip the empty line and new line char
echo json_encode(file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));
```

Comment: not sure why but json solved my problem, thanks for the solution.